# Outputting etc/passwd, removing comments and filtering it

Tags: bash, command

I'm trying to finish an assignment where I have to write a command line that displays the output of a cat /etc/passwd command with a bunch of filtering
I have tried the following

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /etc/passwd | grep -v '\#' | sed '1!n;d' | cut -d':' -f1 | rev | sort -r | awk 'NR>= ENVIRON["FT_LINE1"] && NR<= ENVIRON["FT_LINE2"]' | paste -s -d"," - | sed 's/,/, /g' | sed 's/$/./' | tr -d '\n'
```

but it's not giving any results when I execute it ( I simply do ./name.sh )
Your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: When debugging something like this, I add one command after the other until I reach the blocking command.  I set FT_LINE1 = 1 and FT_LINE2 = 2.  I than ran your code and it worked!  It worked in `bash` and `sh`.  Is `name.sh` executable?  Another point, if your /etc/passwd file readable (it should)?  Are the value of FT_LINE1 and FT_LINE2 too small or too large?  Is FT_LINE2 > FT_LINE1 ?   Add one command at a time in `name.sh` and find which one is not returning a good result and move on from there.

Comment: @Nic3500 how do you set FT_LINE1 = 1 and FT_LINE2 = 2 exactly? thank you.

Comment: ah I see.  I did this: `export FT_LINE1=1` and `export FT_LINE2=7`.  This will then extract users between lines 0 and 8 of your password file (since you have <= and >=, it includes lines 1 and 7).  Then since both variables exit in the environment, the `awk` command will now what values to use.

Comment: @Nic3500 I tried doing it but it still couldn't read anything, am I doing something wrong? https://prnt.sc/k7i8js

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments we added, looks like you are just missing the environment variables set to some value for your code to work.  Modify your script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Modify these values as required
export FT_LINE1=3
export FT_LINE2=8    

cat /etc/passwd | \
    grep -v '\#' | \
    sed '1!n;d' | \
    cut -d':' -f1 | \
    rev | \
    sort -r | \
    awk 'NR>= ENVIRON["FT_LINE1"] && NR<= ENVIRON["FT_LINE2"]' | \
    paste -s -d"," - | \
    sed 's/,/, /g' | \
    sed 's/$/./' | \
    tr -d '\n'
```

The `\` is to continue the command on the next line.  I find it easier to read and debug this way.

The values of FT_LINE1 and FT_LINE2 could be read from arguments, or set in the shell environment outside of the script as well.